Programatically finding the target of a GitHub revert PR
In GitHub it's possible to revert a PR. This creates a new PR with a comment such as Reverts REPOSITORY_NAME#1234. I want to do some data analysis, including looking at the time between the original PR and the revert PR.
Is it possible to determine which PR given PR reverts? Ideally, I'd like to do this programmatically through the GitHub API or some other source that doesn't require manual intervention.

You'll have to look at git log for Reverts REPOSITORY_NAME#1234 and hope it's correct.
